# Populating Textbox based on selecting a dropdown list value in mvc4

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Im using Json to populate some textbox which the value of the textbox is coming from the db. for the event to fire, user must select an email address from a drop down. then populate the textbox with the neccessary values. below is my code but its not returning anything if im running it.

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
        GetUserInfo($("#EmailAddress"));
    });

    function GetUserInfo(e) {
        var EmailId = $(e).val();
        console.log(EmailId);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfo", "Permit")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { EmailAddress: EmailId },
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#FirstName").attr("value", msg);
            $("#LastName").attr("value", msg);
            $("#MobileNumber").attr("value", msg);
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
  <p class="input-wrap">
  @Html.Label("Select Email Address")
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>Model.contactInfo.EmailAddress, new SelectList (Model.AllEmployeeEmail,"Value","Text"),"----select One----", new { @class = "required span12",  onchange = "getEmail(this);"})
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.contactInfo.EmailAddress)
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
  <p class="input-wrap">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.contactInfo.FirstName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.contactInfo.FirstName, new { @class = "required span12" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.contactInfo.FirstName)
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
  <p class="input-wrap">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.contactInfo.LastName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.contactInfo.LastName, new { @class = "required span12" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.contactInfo.LastName)
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
  <p class="input-wrap">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.contactInfo.MobileNumber)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.contactInfo.MobileNumber, new { @class = "required span12" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.contactInfo.MobileNumber)
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
  </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetUserInfo(string Email)
{
   // ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo();
   var info = from ci in db.ContactInfo
              join cci in db.CompanyContactInfo on ci.Id equals cci.ContactInfoId
              join cr in db.CompanyReg on cci.CompanyRegId equals cr.Id
              where cr.CompanyRegCode == User.Identity.Name
              select new SelectListItem() { Value = ci.Id.ToString(), Text = ci.EmailAddress };

   return Json(info, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Please Help me. I know im missing something. I just dont know what is it. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

change this

`data: { EmailAddress: EmailId },`

in your jquery POST to

`data: { Email: EmailId },`

because your action `GetUserInfo` accepts a string parameter named "Email" and not "EmailAddress". Both should be same.

Answer (score 0):

you should give the post data same as the parameters in server code. In the above case you should give **Email** instead of **EmailAddress**

```
function GetUserInfo(e) {
    var EmailId = $(e).val();
    console.log(EmailId);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUserInfo", "Permit")',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { Email: EmailId },
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#FirstName").attr("value", msg);
        $("#LastName").attr("value", msg);
        $("#MobileNumber").attr("value", msg);
    },
    error: function () { }
});
```

Comment: Im still having the same issue.

Comment: @HarunaAdo put an alert in the success event in ajax. check whether it happens or not.

Comment: I used the alert this way     

                alert(msg);
       
 and i got the following error [object Object], [object Object]

Comment: where did you put the alert? in success? or in error??

Comment: @AnnopJoshi I added the alert on success

Comment: @HarunaAdo replace your alert with this alert(JSON.stringify(msg)). and find what you are getting

Comment: @AnnopJoshi Now i got nothing...is still not working

Comment: @HarunaAdo which means there is no data for that email id

Comment: @AnnopJoshi Pls what can i do to fix this?